Is there something like createContext/useContext in Odoo OWL?
Is there a way in Odoo's Owl to have a reactive context that behaves like createContext and useContext in React?
Detailed description
I'm refactoring an App using the new version Odoo's Owl (2.4.1).  The tree of Owl Components look like this:
<TravelHomeApp>
  <TravelArchiveSwitch>
     <OnOffToggleWidget>
  <AddTravelButton>
  <TravelHomeTabs>
     <TravelHomeTab tab="sale">
     <TravelHomeTab tab="preparation">
     ...
  <TravelTable tab="props.current_tab">

The top-level component TravelHomeApp owns most of the state; for instance, the current_tab; most of the children get it now because we pass current_tab as a prop in every place.
However, this hinders refactors to include more components and also the TravelHomeTab would be the natural place to update the current_tab.
Attempts to solve it
I have been trying to use 'useSubEnv' like this:
class TravelHomeTab extends BaseComponent {
    static template = "TravelHomeTab";
    static props = ["tab", "archived", "hidden", "icon_classes", "img_src"];

    state = useState({ active: false, });

    setup() {
        useEffect(
            (currentTab) => {
                console.log("TravelHomeTab::useEffect", { currentTab, env: this.env });
            },
            () => [this.env.currentTab]
        );
    }
}

class TravelHomeTabs extends Component {
     static template = "TravelHomeTabs";
     static components = { TravelHomeTab };
     /// etc...
}

class TravelHomeApp extends Component {
    static template = "TravelHomeApp";
    static components = { TravelHomeTabs, TravelTable, TravelArchiveSwitch, AddTravelButton };

    state = useState({
        current_tab: "tab_sale",
        archived: false,
    });
    setup() {
        useSubEnv({
            currentTab: this.state.current_tab,
            setCurrentTab: (tab) => {this.state.current_tab = tab},
        });
    }
}

What I see in the logs is that 'this.env' is not reactive (no Proxy), and therefore calling env.setCurrentTab from TravelHomeTab won't trigger any updates in the inside TravelHomeTabs and TravelHomeTab itself.  The useEffect is not being called.
Is there a way to keep this "long-distance" context like createContext and useContext in React?  Maybe combination of useSubEnv with reactive?

